# App crashes after instant run if java.util.Calendar.getInstance() is present in code

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

after adding `val x = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().time` to the code, app crashes when I try to apply instant changes (Ctrl + F10) in Android Studio as soon as class containing Calendar variable is called.

The odd thing is that it works by stopping and running app again, problem seems to only persist with instant run.

this is error stack trace after the crash

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: uk.co.projectnamespace.firstapp, PID: 24380
    java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Illegal class access: 'uk.co.projectnamespace.firstapp.service.FirstAppDAOFirebaseImpl$override' attempting to access 'kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker' (declaration of 'uk.co.projectnamespace.firstapp.service.FirstAppDAOFirebaseImpl$override' appears in /data/data/uk.co.projectnamespace.firstapp/files/instant-run/dex-temp/reload0x0000.dex)
        at uk.co.projectnamespace.firstapp.service.FirstAppDAOFirebaseImpl$override.saveDonationMaster(FirstAppDAOFirebaseImpl.kt:95)
        at uk.co.projectnamespace.firstapp.service.FirstAppDAOFirebaseImpl$override.saveDonation(FirstAppDAOFirebaseImpl.kt:43)
```

Has anyone encountered similar problem, and is there a way around it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to disable instant run and run app afterwards?

Comment: Personally I never use Instant Run. Having to think about what may be affected by it adds another dimension to the complexity of debugging apps. In my experience it's not completely reliable. My experience may be obsolete, but who's going to take the time to make sure?

Comment: Thanks guys, was hoping there there will be a way to keep using instant run since it greatly reduces deployment time between code changes

Answer (score 0):

```
Its working fine 

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.smartclient.R


class MainK : AppCompatActivity()
{

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        val x = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().time

        System.out.print(x)
        Toast.makeText(this,"Time: "+x,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```